# Understanding suspension in the model category of chain complexes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, model-categories

In a model category $C$ and $X \in C$ we can define $\Sigma X$ as the homotopy pushout of $$* \leftarrow X \rightarrow * $$
letting $*$ denote the terminal object.

The way I understand it is that if $C = \text{Ch}_+(R-\text{Mod})$ with the projective model structure, if $D$ is a chain complex, $\Sigma D = D[-1]$ where $D[-1]_n = D_{n-1}$. I believe this is true because of the case when $D = C_*(X;R)$, where $X$ is some topological space.

Consider the map

$$C_*(X;R) \rightarrow C_*(C X;R)$$

where $CX$ is the cone over $X$ and note that it is a cofibrant replacement for $C_*(X) \rightarrow *$ in this case and we can thus deduce from some basic algebraic topology that $\Sigma C_*(X;R) \approx C_*(\Sigma X;R)$ which is weakly equivalent as a chain complex to $C_*(X;R)[-1]$.

First of all, is my intuition for this correct? Is $\Sigma D = D[-1]$ for general $D$? I have no clue how to generalize this argument to general chain complexes $D$ so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try proving that the cofibrant replacement of the terminal map is the cone on $D$ (mapping cone of the identity). From here it should be pretty clear how to proceed.

Comment: @ConnorMalin : I don't think $D\to Cone(D)$ is a cofibration in general, as the quotient is not made up of projectives.

Comment: The way I think of it is I write any chain complex canonically as a homotopy colimit of complexes concentrated in degree $0$, and then prove the result for those, using projective resolutions (if $P\to A$ is a projective resolution, $A\to (P\to A)$ is a cofibration, and $(P\to A)$ is $\simeq *$, so the quotient is $P[-1]\simeq A[-1]$ ) (but this is clearly overkill, I'd say the safest way without overkill is to do it using more general projective resolutions; probably the mapping cone of the resolution $P\to D$ should do it)

Comment: Yes, if you take a resolution and then use the mapping cone it works. Though it is bizarre that in top the inclusion into the mapping cone is always a cofibration (at least a Hurewicz cofibration). I guess it probably is only a cofibration in general if the domain of your map is cofibrant and who knows what requirement on the codomain (maybe fibrant?).